# Eureka dashboard returns 404 after running in docker container. But it works fine in localhost

Tags: spring, docker, netflix-eureka, discovery

Eureka dashboard returns 404 after running in a docker container. But it works fine in localhost. I used latest Spring Boot version 2.1.2 and Spring cloud version Greenwich RC2. I can able to see the Eureka dashboard locally. But after creating a container image and binding a port number successfully, I can't see the eureka dashboard UI. It throws "/error" and 404.

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.1.2.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath('se.transmode.gradle:gradle-docker:1.2') 
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'docker'

group = 'gcr.io/sc-cloud-rnd'


if(hasProperty('cmdGroup')) { 
    group = cmdGroup 
}


sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

project.version=getversion()

def getversion() {
    def p = new Properties()
        file("app_version.properties").withInputStream { p.load(it) }
        return p.getProperty("major")+"."+p.getProperty("minor")+"."+p.getProperty("release");
}


jar {
    baseName = 'discovery'
     gradle.taskGraph.whenReady{ taskGraph ->        
        manifest {
            attributes(
     "Implementation-Date": new java.util.Date().toString(),
     "Implementation-Version":project.version
            )
        }        
    }
}



repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', 'Greenwich.RC2')
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    compile group: 'net.rakugakibox.spring.boot', name: 'logback-access-spring-boot-starter', version: '2.7.1'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

processResources {
  filesMatching('bootstrap.yml') { expand(project.properties) }
}


task copyJar(type: Copy) {
    dependsOn   'build'
    from        "build/libs/discovery-${project.version}.jar"
    into        'build/docker'
}

task buildDocker(type: Docker, dependsOn: copyJar) {
    push = false
    if(project.hasProperty('push2Repo')) {
    push = push2Repo
    }
    baseImage "openjdk:8u151"
    exposePort 8761
    runCommand("mkdir discovery")
    addFile("discovery-${project.version}.jar","discovery/")
    workingDir("/discovery")
    runCommand("unzip -q discovery-${project.version}.jar")
    entryPoint(["java","-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions","-XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap","-XX:MaxRAMFraction=1","-XshowSettings:vm","-cp", "/discovery-config:.","org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"])
}
```

application.yml

```
spring:
    main:
        show_banner: false
    application:
        name: discovery
server:
    port: 8761
eureka:
    instance:
        preferIpAddress: true                
    client:
        registerWithEureka: false
        fetchRegistry: false
        useDnsForFetchingServiceUrls: false
        serviceUrl:
            defaultZone: http://${CONFIG_DISCOVERY_HOST:discovery}:${CONFIG_DISCOVERY_PORT:8761}/eureka/
    server:
        waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 0
        enable-self-preservation: false
```

main class file

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class DiscoveryApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DiscoveryApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Gradle command to create a Docker image

```
gradle buildDocker
```

docker run command 
docker run -d -p 8761:8761 --name=discovery gcr.io/sc-cloud-rnd/discovery:1.0.1

Comment: Interesting question! I've got some remarks: What's in your `bootstrap.yml`? Did you inspect the log files?

Comment: my boostrap.yml file is given below.

Comment: spring:
  application:
    name: discovery
  cloud:
        config:
            enabled: false  
info:
    app: 
        name: discovery
        project: "Eureka - Discovery Server"
        version: 1.0.0

Comment: I don't know why this errror came. I solved this issue by developing fresh start.